# concatenate img src string

Tags: php, concatenation, echo, image

I want to display a image from the database by using an `img` tag. Here is my code:

```
if(  !empty( $cat_id ) ) {
    $cats = getImagesByCategory( $cat_id );
    foreach( $cats as $image ) {
        $id = $image['id'];

        echo <<<IMAGE
        <img src="images/'.$category['name']. '/' .$image['name'].'" />
IMAGE;
```

I'm getting a error on the img tag: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or T_NUM_STRING`

I'm clearly concatenating wrong - how can I fix this error?

Comment: RTfineM, please: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing

Comment: @Esailija No, that would result in an `Unexpected end` error, since PHP wouldn't be able to find the end token of the HEREDOC, assuming the rest of the entire document to be HEREDOC. This error here is because of wrong variable interpolation syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<img>` tag is broken:

```
<img src="images/'.$category['name']. '/' .$image['name'].'" />
                ^^^                ^^^   ^^^            ^^^
```

You're using `heredoc` syntax, you don't do string concatenation in `heredoc`.  Try something along the lines of:

```
<img src="images/$category[name]/$image[name]" />
```

Cheers

Comment: I modified my code to this

   



 `if(  !empty( $cat_id ) ) {
  $cats = getImagesByCategory( $cat_id );
  foreach( $cats as $image ) {
   $id = $image['id'];
   $cat_name = $category['name'];
   $img_name = $image['name'];
echo<<<IMAGE
 <img src="images/$cat_name/$img_name>
IMAGE;

  }
 }
 ?>`

And a broken img box shows up under the first category but when I select another category no images show up even though there are images in that category

Comment: Look at the `src` attribute of your image tag.  Hint: there's something important missing there.

Answer (score 1):

Learning to use the [`printf()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.printf.php) family of functions will be extremely useful to you in the long run.

```
printf('<img src="images/%s/%s"/>', $category['name'], $image['name']);
```

Comment: And `printf()` is a function in PHP, as well as pretty much every other language ever. Learn it. Love it. Click the function name, it's a link to the PHP docs.

Answer (score -1):

You had a mix of ' and " in your echo statement.

Just make the echo like this:

```
echo '<img src="images/' . $category['name'] . '/' . $image['name'].'"/>'
```